# How to use Scale tool when Georeferencing Raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, georeferencing, scale

I'm georeferencing a bunch of maps in ArcMap 10.0.  The Shift and Rotate commands are pretty easy to use, no problems there.  But whenever I use the Scale command, the image completely changes position.  Is there a way to put an anchor down (similar to the rotate tool)?  I feel like I must be missing something but haven't figured out what it is yet.  I don't want to rubbersheet them into place, so I'm trying not to use control points until I have it in position, but first I need to make sure the scale bar on the map matches the distance it's supposed to.

Edit: Asking a question does wonders in finding an answer, even when nobody has answered yet.  I found the Rescale_management tool and will use that to set the scale properly first, then position.  If the length of the scale bar is 1256ft and it should be 1200ft, I'll use a factor of .9554 in the X and the Y directions.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Just to throw my hat in the ring...  I never use the scale tools.  I use control points exclusively.  Granted, I'm usually doing a quick georef just to get an idea of where something is, or do a quick-and-dirty digitization of a project area for a map in a proposal or bid.  I've never had any issues, even with maps that are rotated strangely or at a weird scale.  I just make sure that the points I'm using are reliable and I try to distribute them across the image.  That's my two cents.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin that georeferencing is best accomplished using ground control points and the georeferencing toolbar.  Rotate, shift and scale within the georeferencing toolbar are usually done before adding links.

Comment: Is there a way to use control points, but force the map to NOT change shape?  Basically using the control points to only Scale, Shift and Rotate the map?

Comment: Put in a control point with Auto Adjust turned off and just stack it. Select a zero-order polynomial transformation. Then hit rectify and see what the copy looks like. With just one stacked control point, it shouldn't skew your raster at all. It's also interesting to note that the first 3 control points only align, rotate, and scale without skewing (at least in my experience ;)).

Comment: I only ever use the Scale tool by clicking in the **middle** of the image you have Fit to Display - then move the mouse a little to see which way scales it out versus in.

Comment: In the end I found that the scale bar was out by 50 ft, so I ended up ignoring it.  However, I wasn't able to find a way to scale the map to that bar with any accurate success.  Georeferencing, the way it's set up, is fine if you are working directly with real world points and coordinates, or at least topographical features.  But to georeference to something abstract, like a scale bar, is much harder than it seems it should be. C'est la vie.

Comment: If you're georeferencing something just based on the graphical scale bar, you can just create a temporary line feature in a shapefile with the same length as your scale bar and georeference to that using control points.

Comment: That's the rub.  It' not the scale bar alone, but rather a map that needs to be referenced to topography, that also has a scale bar.  Which makes me think that a two part process would work the best.  Scale it as @Dan C suggests, "rectify" or just "update georeferencing", then only use shift and rotate as the previous scale adjustment should stick.  I'll have to try that next time, thanks!