# How to georeference a .jpg image with only a scale bar and no basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, scale-bar

I have a building blueprint image that I need to calculate the sq ft for. However I have no reference or basemap to manually georeference in ArcMap. There is a scale bar on the image. How can I use the scale bar to georeference this image and calculate the sq. ft?

Answer (score 2):

The problem I find with scale bars in general is if the original image was altered in anyway it would be incorrect...say from an 8x11 to 11x17. This would be off quite a lot.

My attempt would be to load the image into ArcMap and as best as you can get the scale to match your 'measurement tool'. Although this may be challenging; for example your image says, '1in = 100feet', this will change based on the size of the image. Match the scale as best as you can. I'd then digitize the blueprint within arcmap as a polygon and then calculate the SQ ft. in the attribute table.

Comment: I didn't even think to do that, that might work as a quick option, an estimate. Do you know if there is some way to tell arcmap by digitizing a line and telling it that line IS 100 ft and then it will use that as a reference. THis is similar to Image J from what I remember if you've ever used that software. THANKS!

Comment: You may want to read this post. I think you'll have to use georeferenceing for that. [Georef raster](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52436/how-to-use-scale-tool-when-georeferencing-raster-in-arcmap)